# How can I find a style trigger-embedded element by name in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, contentcontrol

First, the heart of the question: If an element is assigned as the Content of a ContentControl via a style trigger, I can't seem to find it by name.

Now, for more detail: I have a panel that varies greatly in its layout and functionality based on its data context, which is a bug from a bug depot. When that bug is null, it is a search form, when it is non-null, it is a simple viewer for properties of that bug. The XAML then look something like:

```
<ContentControl DataContext="...">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    ...
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox Name="Waldo"/>
                            <Button .../>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

When the user clicks the button that sits alongside the text box, I get a callback in the code behind. From that point I'd like to be able to access various properties of the text box. The question is, where's **Waldo**? :)

In the code behind I have tried a few variants of the following, all with little success:

```
this.FindName("Waldo"); // Always returns null
```

I've seen a lot of discussion on this topic as it relates to [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820201/how-to-access-a-wpf-control-located-in-a-controltemplate)  but not as it relates to setting content directly with triggers. Maybe it's because I am violating all sorts of best practices by doing this :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If an element is assigned as the `Content` of a `ContentControl` via a style trigger, I can't seem to find it by name.

If you needed to access to the `Content` before trigger occurs, it would most likely not possible. In this situation, the main thing to get access after the DataTrigger occurs.

> I am violating all sorts of best practices by doing this

Maybe it's not the right way to work with the Сontrol in WPF, the more that you still need access to *dynamic* content, which can later be changed. But in any case, there are two ways to work with the Сontrol - it's like now and in the MVVM style. MVVM style is best suited for large and less complex applications with different business logic. If in your case for easy application, in this situation, I do not see anything wrong with that. In addition to doing a project in MVVM style need from scratch, combine conventional method and the correct method is not a good way.

I created a small example to demonstrate access controls for a given situation. There is a property that corresponds to the type of Content, the default is `Init`. If you assigns *null* for this property, the dynamic Content is loaded.

That's how I get access to `TextBox`:

```
private void GetAccessToTextBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox MyTextBox = null;
    StackPanel panel = MainContentControl.Content as StackPanel;

    foreach (object child in panel.Children)
    {
        if (child is TextBox)
        {
            MyTextBox = child as TextBox;
        }
    }

    if (MyTextBox != null) 
    {
        MyTextBox.Background = Brushes.Gainsboro;
        MyTextBox.Height = 100;
        MyTextBox.Text = "Got access to me!";
    }
}
```

Below it's a full example:

**`XAML`**

```
<Window x:Class="AccessToElementInContentControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:AccessToElementInContentControl"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <this:TestData />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Label Content="InitContent"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TypeContent}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <StackPanel Name="NullStackPanel">
                                <TextBox Name="Waldo" Text="DynamicText" />
                                <Button Width="100" Height="30" Content="DynamicButton" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Name="MainContentControl" />

        <Button Name="SetContentType"
                Width="100"
                Height="30" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Content="SetContentType"
                Click="SetContentType_Click" />

        <Button Name="GetAccessToButton"
                Width="110"
                Height="30" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Content="GetAccessToTextBox"
                Click="GetAccessToTextBox_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SetContentType_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestData test = this.DataContext as TestData;

        test.TypeContent = null;
    }

    private void GetAccessToTextBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox MyTextBox = null;
        StackPanel panel = MainContentControl.Content as StackPanel;

        foreach (object child in panel.Children)
        {
           if (child is TextBox)
           {
                MyTextBox = child as TextBox;
           }
        }

        if (MyTextBox != null) 
        {
            MyTextBox.Background = Brushes.Gainsboro;
            MyTextBox.Height = 100;
            MyTextBox.Text = "Got access to me!";
        }
    }
}

public class TestData : NotificationObject
{
    private string _typeContent = "Init";

    public string TypeContent
    {
        get
        {
            return _typeContent;
        }

        set
        {
            _typeContent = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TypeContent");   
        }
    }
}

public class NotificationObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful and detailed explanation! This approach has the property that it forces knowledge of the structure of the UI into the code-behind (namely that the text box we are searching for is a child of a named StackPanel), but it seems like it is the least painful approach overall.

Like you said, it's probably best to not get too caught up in the V/VM split for a small application :)

Comment: A little quick to jump the gun Anatoliy, it merely slipped my mind and I stepped away from the computer for a while. Despite the antagonistic response I went ahead and gave credit where it's due :) It was a great answer, thanks again.