# How can I access a named element of a ControlTemplate through code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I want to access one of the named elements within the original control template that another element is using, in the code-behind.

This is an example of the XAML code (obviously the original is more complicated, or I'd just be doing this in XAML):

```
<Window x:Class="Temp.MainWindow" Title="MainWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Expander Header="Some header">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid Name="MyGrid"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Expander Name="expander" Template="{DynamicResource MyTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What I've tried:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Grid grid = expander.Template.FindName("MyGrid", expander) as Grid;
}
```

I've also tried

```
Grid grid = expander.Template.Resources.FindName("MyGrid") as Grid;
```

But `g` is always `null`.

I've looked at:

- [How do I access an element of a control template from within code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126700/how-do-i-access-an-element-of-a-control-template-from-within-code-behind)
- [How to access a WPF control located in a ControlTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820201/how-to-access-a-wpf-control-located-in-a-controltemplate)
- [How do I programmatically interact with template-generated elements Part I](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2007/03/16/how-do-i-programmatically-interact-with-template-generated-elements-part-i/)

The links above are how I got the code I'm working with, but for some reason, `g` is just always `null`.  Am I doing something wrong with the ContentTemplate?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until the template is applied to the control

```
protected override OnApplyTemplate()
{
    Grid grid = Template.FindName("YourTemplateName") as Grid;
}
```

The real problem here is that you're mixing technologies. You're attempting to use something meant for grabbing the template of a lookless control, in the behind code of the main window. I would be surprised if you didn't run into more issues.

Instead, I would suggest looking into [How to Create Lookless Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14340/Creating-a-look-less-custom-control-in-WPF) and redesigning your application. It wouldn't take much effort and it would all play nice together.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work (`grid` is still `null`).  I'll look into the Lookless Controls, I'm discovering that I don't understand WPF nearly as well as I thought I did.
As a temporary fix, I guess I'll avoid using the templates and just use the same code repeatedly, until I get time to look at that article in more detail.

Comment: @Debra yeah it's not your fault. It takes years to get all of the disciplines you need in order to make everything play nice together. The technologies do mix a little, but once you start doing complex things with them wonky things start happening. If I could point you in a direction it would be to learn the MVVM architecture and learn how to build lookless controls. You'll thank yourself and be way further than most.